# Nexmo audio sampling rate

Tags: audio, vonage

We have connected the Nexmo Voice WebSocket API (telephony) with Google Voice Recognition API but the quality is poor. We assume that the reason is sampling rate. Google requires 16KHZ but not upsampled. Does Nexmo support this?
See our example in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIxS_CF3t00

Answer (score 0):

Nexmos voice core runs at 16bit/16kHz but we are limited to whatever audio the phone company delivers the call into us at, generally this is 8Khz G.711 codec.

We do up-sample but as you've found that doesn't always work great with speech recognition API's. 
I haven't tested out the Google API's yet myself but its very near the top of my todo list.
In the mean time you might want to take a look at the IBM Watson APIs as they have a Narrowband speech model which seems to work much better with telephony. There's some sample code for that here https://github.com/nexmo-community/voice-watson-speechtotext